# How far down can I use this pointer?

Tags: c, string, memory, pointers, reference

Assuming  **if (websValidateUrl(wp, path) < 0)** is true in function below:

```
  int websDefaultHandler(webs_t wp, char_t *urlPrefix, char_t *webDir, int arg,
                            char_t *url, char_t *path, char_t *query)
    {
        websStatType    sbuf;
        char_t          *lpath, *tmp, *date;
        int             bytes, flags, nchars;

    a_assert(websValid(wp));
    a_assert(url && *url);
    a_assert(path);
    a_assert(query);

/*
 *  Validate the URL and ensure that ".."s don't give access to unwanted files
 */
    flags = websGetRequestFlags(wp);

    if (websValidateUrl(wp, path) < 0)         
    {
        websError(wp, 500, T("Invalid URL %s"), url); //points to valid string "/index.html"
        return 1;
    }
}
```

`url` is then passed into here, where fmt is iterated with [va_start()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/):

```
void websError(webs_t wp, int code, char_t *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list     args;
    char_t      *msg, *userMsg, *buf;
   char_t*     safeUrl = NULL;
   char_t*     safeMsg = NULL;
#ifdef qRichErrorPage
   static int reEntry = 0;
   int errorOk;
#endif

    a_assert(websValid(wp));
    a_assert(fmt);

    websStats.errors++;

   /* remove any dangerous characters in the url, and replace the string in the 
    * wp structure. The webs_t cleanup code will free this memory for us.
    */
   safeUrl = websSafeUrl(wp->url);
   bfreeSafe(B_L, wp->url);
   wp->url = safeUrl;

    va_start(args, fmt);  //AT this point args is a bad pointer??
    userMsg = NULL;
    fmtValloc(&userMsg, WEBS_BUFSIZE, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
.
.
.
```

By the time we get to `va_start(args, fmt);` args contains some weird characters, not the "/index.html" I was expecting.

This pointer was allocated at the level higher than the first function but shouldn't it still be there as it is valid in websDefaultHandler?

In general what is the best practice for doing something like this? Do I need to allocate memoery again for it in websDefaultHandler before passing it to  websError()?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "args contains some weird characters"? `args` isn't the same thing as the string that you passed as the fourth argument to `websError`, it's a magic thing that describes the remaining arguments to `websError`. (2) Is the `url` you're passing into `websError` by any chance the same string as `wp->url`? And, if so, does `bfreeSafe(B_L,wp->url)` free it? Because if so, you've just freed it before trying to use it.

Comment: yes, it is clearing it out with bfreeSafe() If you copy the above to an answer I can accept it. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Already said in comments, but pulling out into an actual answer since it seems to be the issue here:)

If it happens that the `url` being passed into `websError` is the same string (meaning, the same piece of memory) as `wp->url`, then that call to `bfreeSafe` is freeing it before `fmtValloc` tries to use it, in which case it's no surprise if `fmtValloc` sees something garbled.

Answer (score 2):

Once you initialize `args` with `va_start`, you should be using `va_arg` to retrieve the actual values.

Comment: It looks to me as if `fmtValloc` is a function of the same sort as `vfprintf`, which takes a `va_list` and does its own `va_arg` processing.